# Pipeline with parameters won't call

Tags: intershop

I have a pipeline with three optionals parameters when I try to call it with one parameter, I have an error message :

> Suspected injection of control parameters in storefront request. Aborting request.

It is weird because I copy/paste from an existant pipeline which is working.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ControlParameterInjectionDetector makes the following check:

```
public boolean isRequestLegal(String pipelineName, String startNodeName, Map<String, String[]> parameters)
{
    if ((parameters.containsKey("PageletEntryPointUUID") || parameters.containsKey("PageletEntryPointID")) &&
                    !("ViewContent".equals(pipelineName) && "Start".equals(startNodeName)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (parameters.containsKey("WorkingTemplate"))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```